# Python Pickle Dump 'Wb' parameter

Tags: python, serialization, pickle

In examples of using pickle to save data, I often encounter a second parameter where many people use `'wb'`, for instance:

`pickle.dump(obj, open('save.p', 'wb'))`.

What does the `'wb'` parameter do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is not a pickle parameter, but a parameter for the open function. It means: open for writing and open in binary mode.

You can read more in [the documentation.](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#open)

Answer (score 4):

'wb' means 'write binary' and is used for the file handle: `open('save.p', 'wb'`) which writes the pickeled data into a file.

The code you got is a short version of:

```
handle = open('save.p', 'wb')
pickle.dump(obj, handle)
```